# Proxy in Selenium using phantomjs Driver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, phantomjs

Im having trouble on adding a proxy in selenium using phantomjs driver.
This is my code:

```
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
            proxy.HttpProxy = string.Format("xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx");

            //options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy, "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx");
            service.ProxyType = "HTTP";
            service.Proxy = "222.88.236.236:81";
            service.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
            service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;
            service.WebSecurity = false;
            service.LocalToRemoteUrlAccess = true;
            service.LoadImages = false;
            webDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(service, options);
```

This code here work sometimes. I'm just using List of proxy available in the web. Not so stable.
And also can anyone explain to me the proxy authentication?

Help me please. Im so noob at this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. I guess the biggest problem you got is the proxies you got online.Most of the free proxies you find online were gathered by some port scan techs,which means they themselves are unstable and can be off-line at anytime(seconds to a few minutes).

Find a proxy provider that has it's own servers will solve your problem.

And for the 'authentication', it depends on the provider you are using.

The proxy i'm using have their own VIP mechanism. You have to be registered, and you have to pay for your proxies and then you can gen an 'API'  link.Using this link,you can get your proxies whenever you want(by the HTTP GET method ).

Some providers can also let you modify the 'API',so that you can decide how many proxies you get at a time or how long you want your proxy to live ,etc.